# UIView drawHierarchy creating a black image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to convert my custom `UIView` into `UIImage` using core graphic, but sometimes it turns to black, my whole `UIImage` looks like a black image.

What I noticed is that if the height of my `UIView` is exceeding 4096 regardless what the width is then the produced `UIImage` will be black!

Note 1: my custom `UIView` is loaded from a nib file.

Here is my code:

```
func getImageWithScale(_ scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let size = self.bounds.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 1)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the size returned after applying CGAffineTransform is correct? Like the size is different from the original frame size?

Comment: @Rikh the size from returned from is equal actually to the UIView size, does this has anything with the problem here?

Comment: @ElTomato I already know that

Comment: @MohamMadSalah hi, have you fixed this problem?

Comment: @BohdanSavych unfortunately no

Comment: Use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0). Also make sure that your view is fully visible on screen because drawHierarchy method is only snapshot the visible part.

Comment: `drawHierarchy`, at least in iOS 15, will render some subviews even when the view is transformed off-screen. So, the `drawHierarchy` code might *look* like it's working right, sometimes, and will fail subtly other times.