# Swift - snapshotView function is not working for large UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm creating a sample app for iPad(7th generation).
There I can get a snapshot of a UIView of `A2` size. But it is not working for a `A1` size UiView.

**A2** -> `UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2182, height: 3086))`

**A1** -> `UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3086, height: 4370))`

I gradually reduced the height of A1 (ie. 4370 points) and it started working when height goes below **4096** points.

I checked the apple documentation, but couldn't find any clue. Can anyone explain why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let page = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2182, height: 3086)) // this is working (A2 page size)
    //let page = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3086, height: 4370)) // this is not working (A1 page size)
    
    let pagePreviewContainer = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        page.backgroundColor = .yellow
        self.view.addSubview(page)
        
        let someSubView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 25, height: 25))
        someSubView.backgroundColor = .red
        page.addSubview(someSubView)
        
        pagePreviewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pagePreviewContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        pagePreviewContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        view.addSubview(pagePreviewContainer)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pagePreviewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
            pagePreviewContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
            pagePreviewContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            pagePreviewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100)
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        let previewOfPage = self.page.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
        pagePreviewContainer.addSubview(previewOfPage!)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised you hit the limit at 4096, since it's a power of 2, and textures in graphics systems are always stored in sizes that are powers of two. Since the iPad is a @2x device, the height of the image is actually 8192.

I don't have an exact answer since I've never attempted this, but I have a couple of suggestions.

You could use CoreGraphics and draw the view's layer into an image context. This won't require basically any changes other than changing your snapshot call.

If that still doesn't work, you might have to consider rendering the contents on your view "manually" using CoreGraphics.

You could also render at the highest possible resolution and then scale up the image, if it's not a huge difference it might not be noticeable.

Comment: @EmilionPelaez According to this, it seems core graphics also not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904135/uiview-drawhierarchy-creating-a-black-image

Answer (score 0):

Since the iPad is @2x device and 7th gen iPads have 2048px resolution in height they simply can't capture the View that is larger than 2x2048 = 4096, so as it is a page preview try to resize the output image and make it fits the preview container.

Comment: what do you mean by output image? I'm not using any Core Graphics to generate a snapshot image. Actually using core graphics alright but lacks the performance of snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:) so is not useful for my purpose :)